# Configure pfSense to not give 'potential DNS rebind attack detected' warning for local server

Tags: pfsense, pfsense-2

I am needing to access a local LEMP server through its domain name for a PHP package that uses domain names in every link, making IP address usage not possible for this application.

I can access the domain just fine from devices elsewhere on the www.

pfSense manages two physically separate networks, but accessing the server with the domain brings up the "Potential DNS Rebind attack detected" warning page when accessed from either network, however, using the IP address brings up the server's pages just fine.

The server has a static mapping configured with the domain name set in the configuration in Services DHCP Server.

I have the DNS Forwarder enabled and the Register DHCP static mappings in DNS forwarder is checked.

I am running pfSense 2.1.5.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: [https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can't_I_access_forwarded_ports_on_my_WAN_IP_from_my_LAN/OPTx_networks](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can't_I_access_forwarded_ports_on_my_WAN_IP_from_my_LAN/OPTx_networks)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I resolved the question for myself prior to an answer here. Over the years I have observed the pfSense devs to change the GUI such that configuring requires different steps even through previously configured devices do not require reconfiguration. Currently, it appears MarcoZen below is maintaining an answer, but over the years it is likely to become stale, or a new and better solution will be released.

Answer (score 19):

Its been two years since the question was asked, but I had the same problem (domain name) and SOLVED it by:

1. Log into pfsense via IP address or any working domain name
2. Goto **System -> Advanced -> Admin Access** and under **Alternate Hostnames** - key in your new domain name. You can **add extra domain names** by separating them with **spaces**.

Comment: Just as a point of note (because I just spent the last 20 minutes doing this wrong), the name of the field is a little bit misleading... "hostnames"... it will accept both a hostname AND an FQDN with a different domain than the native/defined domain. So, if the firewall internally is connected to multiple domains, you need to make entries for BOTH the hostname and FQDN. For example... define **con-fw** and **fab-fw** as well as **con-fw.contoso.com** and **fab-fw.fabrikam.com**

Answer (score 4):

Under **System->Advanced->Firewall** and NAT there is an option "*Automatically create outbound NAT rules which assist inbound NAT rules that direct traffic back out to the same subnet it originated from.*"

Comment: I found it is better to use **Services->DNS Resolver->General Settings** and check **Register DHCP leases in the DNS Resolver** and **Register DHCP static mappings in the DNS Resolver** then add the server to the **Host Overrides**.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **System** > **Advanced**, **Firewall/NAT** tab. then you need to enable  three options:

1)  **Pure NAT** for NAT Reflection mode for port forwards
2)  **Enable NAT Reflection for 1:1 NAT** 
3)  **Enable automatic outbound NAT for Reflection**

Click Save.

It solved my issue and if it solves your issue, keep me in your prayers.

Thanks,